# get the list of absent employees for n consecutive days

Tags: sql

i have table that record all the time attendance on daily bases, and i should make a report to show all the employees that didn't punch in for n consecutive days

table called TimeAttendance(Id,Employee,AttendanceDate,CheckIn,CheckOut)

Comment: and there is status that he punched this day or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the requirements you added above, here what you can do

```
select Employee,FromDate=Min(AbsentDate),ToDate=Max(AbsentDate)
from(
select Employee,AbsentDate,count(*) over(partition by Employee,val) as AbsentDays,
       dense_rank() over(partition by Employee order by val) as OrderId
from
(select Employee,AttendanceDate as AbsnetDate,dateadd(d,-row_number() over(partition by Employee order by AttendanceDate),AttendanceDate) as val
from TimeAttendance 
where Status='Absent' -- assuming that if the employee didn't punch the Status will be 'Absent') t) x
where AbsentDays= n -- n is the n consecutive days
group by Employee
```

-- here the correction

```
select Employee,FromDate=Min(AbsentDate),ToDate=Max(AbsentDate)
from(
    select Employee,AbsentDate,count(*) over(partition by Employee,val) as AbsentDays,
           dense_rank() over(partition by Employee order by val) as OrderId
    from
        (select Employee,AttendanceDate as AbsentDate,dateadd(d,-row_number() over(partition by Employee order by AttendanceDate),AttendanceDate) as val
        from TimeAttendance 
        where Status='Absent') as t -- assuming that if the employee didn't punch the Status will be 'Absent') t) x
)as x
where AbsentDays= n -- n is the n consecutive days
group by Employee
```

hope that this will help you

regards